# Reducing the number of bits by 1

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit

Is there a generic way to represent a number containing `n` bits using `n-1` bits; e.g. showing `1001` which has 4 bits using `XXX where X = {0|1}` with 3 bits. Also, the mapping should be able to retrieve the original binary back without any collision.

This [page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2005/10/13/another-of-my-favorite-tricks-reducing-the-number-of-bits-in-a-number-by-1/) is the most relevant reference that I have found so far which tries to count the number of bits, but not reduce the number of bits.

Edit: I knew this sounds impossible, but I'm curious if there exists a workaround to do so!

Comment: So you want to compress an n bit data into `n-1` ? Cool. Then compress `n-1` into `n-2` and down to zero. Perfect compression. You will get a Nobel prize for sure.

Comment: How can you possibly do that?

Comment: 4 bits encode 16 possible values. 3 bits encode 8 possible values. So the answer is NO.

Comment: No. What you're touching on is called compression. There is no generic, perfect compression. Let's pretend we want to compress every 4-bit string down to 3 or fewer bits. There are 2^4 = 16 different 4-bit strings, but only 2 1-bit strings, 4 2-bit strings and 8 3-bit strings, for a total of 14 possible values. You have 16 values that you want to store into 14 slots. Two of them can't be compressed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: There are certain special cases where a bit can be omitted, because it's assumed from other principles.  E.g. the high-order bit of the mantissa of a normalized floating point number is always 1, so it doesn't need to be included in the representation.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you guys, especially with the _Nobel prize_ and the _Pigeonhole principle_. I was looking for a simple trick that makes sense which as you guys posited it's impossible!

Comment: @hmofrad I think you are looking for a compression algorithm. Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Eugene Sh, I'm trying to prove that the worst-case complexity of an algorithm trying to send `n` bits is `n - O(1)`. My problem is with `O(1)` which makes the problem impossible, because I can easily say for sending `n` bits, I only need `n` bits, but I don't know how to rule out the `O(1)` part.

Comment: You know that `O(n) - O(1) = O(n)`, right?

Comment: @Eugene Sh, Well! It's still of order of `O(n)`!

Comment: Of course it is. You need to perform `n` operations serially, so there is no way it would be less than `O(n)`..

Comment: Eugene Sh, I see the difference between `n` operations and the order! I can prove this thing to show it is of order of `O(n)` complexity, but still I need to come up with a way to drop the `O(1)` so that I can show the number of operations is also correct. Anyhow, thanks for the help!

Comment: Only if there is enough redundancy in the data. If that were not so, it would be impossible to compress any data.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2^n possible values with n bits, and 2^(n-1) with (n-1) bits. So you can't convert from the former to the latter losslessly.

If it were at all possible, you could also recursively represent your n-1 bits using n-2 bits, etc. Everything would be representable with 0 bits :)

You get misleaded by the page you linked, which explains that `x &= x-1` removes a `1` in a bit string.

```
  10100
& 10011
= 10000
```

Comment: I see your point here! I knew this thing from the beginning while posting the question. I was thinking to follow this approach to see if we can reduce the number of bits! Anyhow, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You will be very clever if you manage to establish a one-to-one mapping between the 16 numbers

```
0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111
```

and the eight numbers

```
000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111.
```

Comment: I guess you can reduce your example to `n=2` to make it even clearer :) Or to `n=1` ...